# How to resolve path issues in python project?

Tags: python-2.x

I have a project structure as given below:

```
src/
-----test/
---------__init__.py
---------run_test.py
-----moduleA/
---------__init__.py
---------targets.py
---------features.py
---------test_analysis.ipynb
---__init__.py
---logger.py
```

In my targets.py I have the following imports:

```
from src.moduleA import features
from src import logger
```

In my features.py I have the following imports:

```
from src import logger
```

I have set my current working directory to : **src/**

so for now it works fine, however I want to use targets.py and features.py file in my
test_analysis.ipynb

I am importing it like this in notebook:

```
from src.moduleA import features
```

However it gives me the following error :

```
ImportError: No module named src.moduleA
```

**Note: I am using python 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you are required to add `__init__.py` for each of the directories. Otherwise it doesn't understand these folders as packages.